# Place DIVS in 4 corners of overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a development and production version of my site. Because they look identical I want to place a transparent overlay over the development version with white text in each of the 4 corners. Each corner of text reads "DEV MODE". As the user scrolls, the overlay with the text should always display in each of the corners.

Only the Top-Left div of text is showing. Can someone help please?

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

div.fadeMe {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fadeMe .wordsTL {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsBL {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsTR {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsBR {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="fadeMe">
    <div class="wordsTL">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsBL">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsTR">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsBR">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  //Other HTML Page Content behind the overlay
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a couple of `<div>`s with `display: flex;` to accomplish this.

See: https://codepen.io/kboedges/pen/axYroQ

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="dev-overlay">
    <div class="dev-column">
      <div class="dev-row">
        <div class="dev-box">Dev Mode</div>
        <div class="dev-box">Dev Mode</div>
      </div>
      <div class="dev-row">
        <div class="dev-box">Dev Mode</div>
        <div class="dev-box">Dev Mode</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Page Content</h1>
  Love i want to go outside let me go outside nevermind inside is better All of a sudden cat goes crazy chase dog then run away if it fits, i sits Cat ipsum dolor sit amet, murf pratt ungow ungow. Cough furball into food bowl then scratch owner for a new
  one where is my slave? I'm getting hungry so eat grass, throw it back up or leave fur on owners clothes. Curl up and sleep on the freshly laundered towels pushes butt to face.
</div>
```

```
.wrap {
  background: lightpink;
}

.dev-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dev-column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.dev-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dev-box {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to dry your code ...
I rewrote some parts to fix some problems.
Use the position: fixed with the top, left, right and bottom properties to full screen overlay.
But keep in mind that overlap your content will not allow interaction with him.

```css
.fadeMe {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.fadeMe [class^="words"] {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.fadeMe .wordsTL {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.fadeMe .wordsBL {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fadeMe .wordsTR {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.fadeMe .wordsBR {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="fadeMe">
  <span class="wordsTL">DEV MODE</span>
  <span class="wordsTR">DEV MODE</span>
  <span class="wordsBL">DEV MODE</span>
  <span class="wordsBR">DEV MODE</span>
 </div>
 //Other HTML Page Content behind the overlay
</div>
```

Comment: fadeMe [class^="words"] is not a good idea - it will evaluate true for a class such as 'words-asdf', basically any class that starts with 'words' - and that might appear somewhere else within the application. For just 4 classes, you should simply hard-code it. Also it will might evaluate true if other classes are added to the element later, and are placed before the ['words**'] class - as the className will not **begin** with your query value - example [<span class="smtgElse wordsBR">]

Comment: I do not see it that way.
This is a well-defined scope.

Comment: If necessary, it can be improved to improve the structure. It was just a quick response.
Keep in mind that text in pseudo-elements may present a problem in some screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `text-align: right` on each of the right-hand divs.

Alternatively, take the 100% width rule off all of the inner elements and let them fit their contents:

```
.fadeMe > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cw8ehn2v/)

You can do this with one element, by the way (or two if you can't use `body`.

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1h6tfpxc/)

```css
body::before,
body::after,
.lower-watermarks::before,
.lower-watermarks::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 70vh;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  content: 'DEV MODE';
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: arial;
}

body::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.lower-watermarks::before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30vh;
}

.lower-watermarks::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  height: 30vh;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-watermarks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `width: 100%;` setting on each of your `.fadeMe` children.

Also, your `.fadeMe` div currently has a `height: 1000px;` setting that makes it potentially taller than your window, so `wordsBL` and `wordsBR` appear hidden. If you change its height to `100%`, the transparent overlay will appropriately fill the window.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

div.fadeMe {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.fadeMe .wordsTL {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsBL {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsTR {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}

.fadeMe .wordsBR {
  position: absolute;
  /* Position the background text */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Grey text */
  padding: 20px;
  /* Some padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="fadeMe">
    <div class="wordsTL">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsBL">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsTR">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wordsBR">
      <h1>DEV MODE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  //Other HTML Page Content behind the overlay
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the overlay is full-screen, with some text in all four corners: You implementation was good, but the height of your overlay exceeded the size of the page.

Notes:

- do NOT use <heading> elements to just make text bigger - they have a very important semantic, accessibility and SEO role - not a styling role.
- you can add the text through pseudo-elements.
- you can add a shared class to store the share styles - makes code more readable and maintanable.
- do not use unnecessary selectors such as [div.fadeMe] (is there a different type of element that has the .fadeMe class and would require different styling - p.fadeMe / input.fadeMe / etc ? ) - just .fadeMe will do just fine.

```
<div class="fadeMe">
    <div class="words words-TL"></div>
    <div class="words words-BL"></div>
    <div class="words words-TR"></div>
    <div class="words words-BR"></div>
</div>

/* set in relation to the viewport and make it full-size */
.fadeMe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width:100vw; height: 100vh;
    z-index: 10;
    pointer-events: none;

    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    background-color: #000;
}

/* shared styles */
.words {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}
/* individual positions */
.words-TL { top: 0;    left:  0; }
.words-TR { top: 0;    right: 0; }
.words-BL { bottom: 0; left:  0; }
.words-BR { bottom: 0; right: 0; }

/* adding the text for all divs */
.words::before {
    content: 'DEV MODE';
    font-size: 36px;
}
```